# Chaining Animations (iPhone / MonoTouch)

Tags: iphone, animation, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to slide some (custom) tab-like buttons into view.  I don't want them all to move at the same time.  Also, they shouldn't move one at at time (where one slides after the other finishes).

I want each button to begin sliding slightly after the previous.  Preferably it would happen on a curve but just a fixed .1 second offset would be alright too.

Monotouch or Obj-C code is fine.  I'm thinking there is something in the APIs for animating groups of items like this.  Hopefully, at least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`+setAnimationDelay:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationDelay:) to delay the starting time of an animation block, e.g.:

```
tab1.frame = ...
[UIView beginAnimations:...];
tab1.frame = ...
[UIView commitAnimations];

tab2.frame = ...
[UIView beginAnimations:...];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.1f];
tab2.frame = ...
[UIView commitAnimations];

...
```